# Apache Camel with Spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to run a simple application in Apache Camel using spring DSL.
Here is my spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true" />
        <process ref="downloadLogger" />
        <to uri="jms:incomingOrders" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
<bean id="downloadLogger" class="com.test.eip.camel.DownloadLogger"></bean>
```

And here is my Java class for testing:

```
public class CamelSpringTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
    CamelContext camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(appContext, false);
    try {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        camelContext.start();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Hello2");
        camelContext.stop();
    }
}
```

}

I can see Hello and hello2 in my console, but my file is not being moved. I think I'm doing something wrong while creating the camel context. Could you please help? Do I need to add routes explicitly to camelContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. I should have written Thread.sleep() after the context starts. Camel context was stopping even before the file was picked up.

Answer (score 0):

For testing your routes you should rather use http://camel.apache.org/testing.html . This way you won't fall into similar problems. Besides that camel-test provides many helpers like assertions, mocks, test camel context.

The camel-test api may be cumbersome for some developers, that's why I've started developing a small library which hopefully can address some of the boilerplate http://github.com/gmaslowski/camel-test-support